# Leaflet marker cluster by Administrative boundary

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers

Is it possible to perform clustering based on administrative boundary using the [leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin? How would I do that?

I already have the boundary layer.

Comment: While I'm not sure if this is technically feasible, either, another possibility would be to cluster by an attribute (like Admin boundary name as an attribute of the point).  Great idea, though.

Comment: what parameter we use when clustering using marker clusterer plugin? is it distance or what? thank you

Comment: Distance is used to cluster the markers.  See "maxClusterRadius" in the documentation.

Comment: Here is a customized "[markercluster pie charts](http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728)" plugin that supports pie charts showing "edges" by type of event.  This may give you some ideas.